# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream$Builder org.apache.poi-poi-ooxml-5.2.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-poi

I have upgraded from `org.apache.poi-poi-ooxml-5.2.3` to `org.apache.poi-poi-ooxml-5.2.4` due to **Security Violation Threat** in `5.2.3`

Now, I am facing run time exception as `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`

**Exception:**

```
[ERROR] ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/reports/myapp/myreport] due to exception ['org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream$Builder org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream.builder()']
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream$Builder org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream.builder()'
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.newPackage(XSSFWorkbook.java:521) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.4.jar:5.2.4]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:231) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.4.jar:5.2.4]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:227) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.4.jar:5.2.4]
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:215) ~[poi-ooxml-5.2.4.jar:5.2.4]
    at myapp.reports.service.impl.MyReportsExcelExporter.<init>(MyReportsExcelExporter.java:37) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
```

**Code:**

```java
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class MyReportsExcelExporter {
    protected XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    ...
    public MyReportsExcelExporter() {
        this.workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); //Facing issue here, while initializing the workbook.
    }
    ...
}
```

Looking at the version change, it seems like a minor upgrade but now existing code has stopped working.

What's probably wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You will need to add/upgrade **Apache Commons IO** dependency version **>= 2.12.x**.

**Note:** The `builder()` method present in `UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream` got introduced from **2.12.x** version of **commons-io** onwards.

I took the latest dependency of **commons-io** which is **2.14.0** at the time of writing the answer.

**pom.xml** (Maven):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Or

**build.gradle** (Gradle):

```
dependencies {
   implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.14.0'
}
```

It will work.

Comment: Currently using commons-io 2.11.0

Comment: Working after upgrading commons-io 2.11.0 to 2.14.0

As UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream.builder() is not available in commons-io 2.11.0

Comment: This should be the answer. I had the same problem and this fixed it.
Thanks Anish!

Comment: What POI 5.2.4 docs say you should use ancient commons-io versions? https://poi.apache.org/changes.html lists the upgrade to commons-io 2.13.0 but 2.14.0 is ok too. If you provide a link to the incorrect docs, we can fix them.

Comment: @AnishB., I think is should not be `version >=2.7.x` it should be `version >= 2.14.0`. Not sure when was UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream.builder() introduced. Could you please confirm?

Comment: @Prem I have checked all the version from 2.11 to 2.14. The Builder is present from 2.12.0 onwards.

Comment: somehow when downloaded from maven rep `org.apache.poi:poi` dependes on `commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0 (compile)` instead of `2.13.0` (but the pom has the correct version of `2.13.0`

Answer (score 0):

just playing with versions of poi worked out for me, downgraded to the 5.2.2 from 5.2.5 version worked out

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

is what my pom looks like