# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader.getSharedStringsTable()Lorg/apache/poi/xssf/model/SharedStringsTable

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have upgraded the **org.apache.poi-poi-ooxml-4.1.2** to **5.2.4** to fix few vulnerability issues.

After that I got an error mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77256330/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-apache-commons-io-output-unsynchronizedbytearr) and fixed it by adding a dependency **commons-io.commons-io-2.13.0**.

Now I am getting another exception mentioned below.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFReader.getSharedStringsTable()Lorg/apache/poi/xssf/model/SharedStringsTable;
```

I could see the method getSharedStringsTable() in XSSFReader class of poi-ooxml-5.2.4 , but the return type is not SharedStringsTable, its SharedStrings.

I am not sure from where this method is getting invoked (XSSFReader.getSharedStringsTable()) and why its expecting the return type as SharedStringsTable.

Anyone faced the similar issue? Do i need to upgrade any other dependency?

Comment: Can you please share the full stack trace?

Comment: "I am not sure from where this method is getting invoked (XSSFReader.getSharedStringsTable())": The full stack trace will show you this.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your support. Unfortunately i did not get full stack trace. Finally i found the root cause, the particular method is invoked by one of the third party jar. I will explain the details in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In 5.2.4 that method's signature has changed.  It returns an instance implementing the `SharedStrings` interface, not a concrete `SharedStringsTable`.

You would have seen this if you looked at the [Javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/5.2.4/index.html)

This appears to be a change introduced in 5.2.0.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details @Jim Garrison

Answer (score 0):

I did some analysis and identified the root cause of this issue.

XSSFReader.getSharedStringsTable() is not invoked from our source
Actually, it's invoked by another third-party jar called **org.openl.rules-5.22.7**, also it's expecting the return type as SharedStringsTable.

I will try to upgrade the openl.rules jar as the current version is not compatible with the **org.apache.poi-poi-ooxml-5.2.4** [image]